# Merging Flowfiles in NiFi

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using NiFi `Version: 1.11.4`

I want to merge the `flowfiles` in NiFi.

let's say I have 10 flow files like:

```
{
    "id": "d17ebcd8f46456FHFH",
    "serialNumber": "abdERE5",
    "productNumber": "2323EWR",
    "familyName": "P2055DN",
    "modelName": "P2055dn ABC"
}
```

I want to use all `SerialNumber` to query a `Table` and get two fields (`manufacturer`, `deviceId`) for all the Serial Numbers in one go and insert it into a `Table` by matching the `serialNumber`.

I was able to merge the `flowfiles` but after that, I'm not sure how to query data for all `serialNumber` and insert into the table in one go.

Here is the configuration of my `MergeContent`

[image: MergeContent]

Comment: Is merging your issue? You can try MergeRecord. Then you need to give more detail on your query based on the serialnumber.

Comment: No Merging is not but after merging I need to execute a query with an `in` clause in the SQL server DB.
But the way I merge should solve my problem. I was able to do that by first extracting all the `seriaNumber` then merging them as a JSON string. then I was able to get the complete string with `EvaluateJson`.

Comment: in the end, I wanted a string like `'abdERE5','abdERE5','abdERE5'`

Comment: I will do: MergeRecord --> QueryRecord (something like "SELECT DISTINCT serialNumber from FLOWFILE"
You should have as an output , the flowfile containing the unique values of serialNumber